# Sum lines of string of numbers in file.txt

Tags: python

I have the following text file:

```
HAJOS
ALFRED
1896
1

HERSCHMANN
OTTO
1896
2

DRIVAS
DIMITRIOS
1896
3

MALOKINIS
IOANNIS
1896
1

CHASAPIS
SPIRIDON
1896
2
```

I want to sum the 4th line of numbers in each person data. For example I want to sum (1, 2, 3, 1, 2) and print out the result which is 9. If they were next to each other it would be easy, but the problem is they are in a text file and bellow each other.

Comment: what have you tried? Also, are the groups consistent like that (i.e. always four lines with an empty line between them) or are there special cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the grouping is completely consistent, you just need slicing:

```
import itertools
sum(int(i) for i in itertools.islice(open(filename), 3, None, 5))
```